# Copying files from one folder to another using python

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to copy files from selected subfolders and paste them to selected subfolders using python. I have only copied files from one folder to another before without having to deal with selected folders/subfolders. But since there are many subfolders from which I need to copy the files to selected subfolders, I am having a hard time figuring that part out.

Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please, explain in detail and with code, what part you're having trouble with.  It isn't clear which part of the copying you're having trouble with and you haven't asked any specific question.

Comment: What you want to do can be acomplished with `os.walk` from `os` module. `os.walk(dir)` returns a generator object from the directory you pass as parameter, containing all files, directories and subdirectories inside it. Combining it with `open()` and `os.mkdir()`, you can iterate over the generator object and copy everything from a selected directory to another.